# Instascan, How to open input content in another page using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, instascan

I'm new in this but I'm learning how to use Javascript/PHP. I'm trying to scan a QR code and pass the content to another PHP page. I'm using form/input field with a button submit, using PHP 'GET' to get the data content, and it works, but is not what I want to do, because I need to avoid the 'button submit', I'm trying to use jQuery to submit the form when the QR is scanned , but it doesn't work, this is my code:

```
    <section class="scans">
      <h2>Scans</h2>
      <ul v-if="scans.length === 0">
        <li class="empty">Ningun escaneo todavia</li>
      </ul>                

      <transition-group name="scans" tag="ul">
        <li v-for="scan in scans" :key="scan.date" :title="scan.content">{{ scan.content }}
           <form id="myform" action="empleados.php" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" name="qr" :key="scan.date" :value="scan.content" />
             <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Registrar Acceso/Salida"/>
$(function() { $("#myform").submit(); });
          </form>
        </li>
      </transition-group>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="preview-container">
    <video id="preview"></video>
  </div>
```

This is the PHP page `empleados.php` and the code to GET the content of the scan:

```
 <?php  
    $info_qr=$_GET['qr'];
```

Comment: Your JS code should go in a `<script>` tag. It should also go *after* the `</form>` tag. However, even if you fix that, it will submit the form immediately, not necessarily when the code is scanned. What event triggers the fact that the code has been scanned and that the form should be submitted?

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach your action to the `onChange` event of the text input

```
<script>
$('input[name$="qr_code"]').on('change', submitForm)

function submitForm() {
    // your ajax request
}
</script>
```

If the `onChange` event doesn't meet your needs try using the event 'keyup' or one of these events:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

And I recommend you move your js code inside of a `<script>` tag

Comment: i don't get it , the onChange will go in the 'form' tag? and the the script code that you post?

Comment: I suggest you review the different ways to include js code in a html document, also check the theory of how the events of the browser works.